# How to Link a Script In WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My script doesn't work in Wordpress. I'm trying to convert my HTML page into a Wordpress Theme.. Ive got the CSS linked..

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/min/mycss.css" />
```

but my script doesn't connect..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="min/myjs.js"></script>
```

i tried the same , using the `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/min/myjs.js"></script>
```

Help?

Comment: you checked where is the actual path of your js and css file

Comment: What errors does it cause?

Comment: the Path is correct, because its working in the HTML version. Errors i see is in the dreamweaver.. it goes red. Means not good right??

Comment: The way you're closing your php tags looks odd to me.  What happens if you remove the space between the `?` and `>` (so `?>`)?

Comment: removed space. still doesnt work.. :-(

Comment: I wouldn't listen to Dreamweaver if its working, it likes to pretend theres an error when there isn't.

Comment: Ok ignored dreamweaver.. still doesnt work :(

Comment: Question: my JS works in my Static HTML pages.. ( Slider and Carousel ) --- I just have to link the js files and it should work in WordPress right???

Comment: The WordPress way to add scripts is with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) ([wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for styles).  But your code looks ok; I suspect there's an error between your two statements.  If you view the page source, does it get as far as the start of the `script` tag?  Are there any errors in your logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't include scripts and stylesheets this way. Use [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts). Assuming this is a custom theme, add the code to the functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts_styles' );

function theme_scripts_styles() {

  // Enqueue scripts and styles here

}
```

In this function use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to queue the files (should be obvious which to use based on the file type!)

Also bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) is not best practice.

Use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), or [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) for parent themes. You can drop the _uri part to get the server paths.

So all together it looks something like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts_styles' );

function theme_scripts_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/min/mycss.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/min/myjs.js', array(), '1.0', true );

}
```

Be sure to read the Codex on the enqueue functions so you know what all the parameters do.

Comment: Wow! thanks,,, I guess i have to read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Awesome! its working now.. anyway i just read some tutorails.. some of them registers the path first then enqueue's them .. is it the same on what you did??

Comment: You can use wp_register_script, which in turn allows you to enqueue them just using the slug (first parameter). Useful if you want to enqueue scripts conditionally. The method above is simplest where you just want to include a script/stylesheet on every page.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code to add your JavaScript link to your wordpress site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/path_to/your_script.js"></script>
```